# How to generate an event on the click of an image?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I am designing a GUI, where I have added logo's to several frames. I want to make the logo's functional so that when they're clicked upon, it returns then to the main menu frame.

For example; I have the following logo created here (In controller class):

```
    LogoTitlePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    LogoTitlePanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    frame.add(LogoTitlePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    LogoImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Acme.png"));
    ImageContainer = new JLabel(LogoImage);
    LogoTitlePanel.add(ImageContainer);
    wholeFramePanel.add(LogoTitlePanel);
    frame.add(wholeFramePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

... and I want the Acme.png image to take them to this frame upon being clicked (In MainMenu class):

```
    frame = new JFrame("Aston Cruise & Maritime Enterprise");
```

Is it possible to accomplish this? if so, how?

Comment: I am not sure about firing event from image but I guess you can easily do that for JLabel component

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Put the image in a (undecorated) `JButton` with an `ActionListener`.  It will respond to mouse or keyboard then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a JButton instead of a JLabel and then just add an ActionListener to the button.

You can make the button look like a label by using:

```
button.setBorderPainted( false );
button.setFocusPainted( false );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ActionListener, try MouseListener...

```
private MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //Code...
    }
}

LogoImage.addMouseListener(listener);
```